# Flow: Object type incompatible with Array<mixed>

Tags: javascript, flowtype, flow-typed

I don’t understand the flow error I’m currently getting. I have a Javascript object of objects (`dataObject`) that I want to convert to an array of objects, so I do so using `Object.values(dataObject)`. Then, I iterate through each object in the array with the following:

```
  const dataObjectArray = Object.values(dataObject);
  return dataObjectArray((data: DataObject) => {
    const { typeA, typeB } = data;
    return {
      TYPE_A: typeA,
      TYPE_B: typeB,
    };
  });
```

But I get the following flowtype error:

[image: flow error]

I’m not sure how to match up the types. Currently my DataObject flow type is

```
type DataObject = {
    typeA: string,
    typeB: string,
};
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type definition for the `Object.values` function has no way to know that the argument passed to it is an object where the values are all the same type. You could just as easily be doing `Object.values({foo: 4, bar: "str"})`. [The type definition is](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/0ce1a0b08d2f074bd7ba897d809cf877b7ab2678/lib/core.js#L49)

```
(any) => Array<mixed>
```

meaning that you are doing `.map` on a value of type `Array<mixed>`.

That means if you want to use it as object, your method will not work. Assuming your "object of objects" is typed as

```
type DataObjects = {
  [string]: DataObject,
}
```

You'd likely be better off doing

```
function values(objs: DataObjects): Array<DataObject> {
  return Object.keys(objs).map(key => objs[key]);
}
```

Comment: I which I could swear on SO - this is so frustrating. Your answer is the literal "best case" the community has had for 2 years. This is pathetic. Ty for the help, take my updoot.

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer to use Object.values() (probably more efficient) and have typing right, you can use a helper function like this:

```
 function objectToValues<A, B>(obj:{[key: A]: B} ): Array<B> {
    return ((Object.values(obj): any): Array<B>)
 }
```

Comment: This works but using `any` is not recommended as it's not allowed in Flow strict files.